# Updating NuGet packages in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc

I just created a new ASP.NET MVC 6 project and wanted to update the NuGet packages to their latest versions (The default project templates are usually very out of date). I noticed the following updates were possible:

- Antlr.3.4.1.9004      > Antlr.3.5.0.2
- Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4 > Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8
- WebGrease.1.5.2       > WebGrease.1.6.0

When I try to upgrade these packages wither using the NuGet package dialog or updating the version numbers in the project.json file for Newtonsoft.json, I get errors.

> **1)** Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Not implemented
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))          0
>
> **2)** Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line Error      NuGet Package
>   Restore failed for one or more packages. See details in the Output
>   window.   Mvc6ProjectName C:[PATH TO MY FOLDER]\Source\Mvc6ProjectName\project.json  0
>
> **3)** Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Dependency
>   Newtonsoft.Json >= 6.0.8 could not be
>   resolved  Mvc6Boilerplate C:\Git\ASP.NET-MVC-Boilerplate\Source\MVC6\Mvc6Boilerplate\project.json 19

I also have a MVC project and am using the latest NuGet packages there so why can't I upgrade these packages? Is this to do with the fact that there is no more web.config file where we can specify runtime assemblyBinding's:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**Update 1**

When I try to update Newtonsoft.Json from the package manager console, I get the error below:

> PM> Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -ProjectName Mvc6Boilerplate -Version 6.0.8 
>   Package with the Id 'Newtonsoft.Json' is not installed to project 'Mvc6Boilerplate'.

It seems that Newtonsoft.Json is not installed in the default MVC 6 project but is installed as a dependency of another project. This NuGet package is not actually displayed in the Nuget Package Manager either but is displayed in the project.json file and also under the References->DNX and DNX Core tree view item.

When I try to explicitly install the Newtonsoft.Json package, it does upgrade to 6.0.8 but I then get the errors I listed above.

Comment: If you go to the Output Window, change the dropdown to "Package Manager", what errors can you find there? I haven't seen issues when upgrading packages. I have manually added `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` to the xproj files to handle the binding issue.

Comment: See my update 1 above. I tried adding AutoGenerateBindingRedirects but it does not help.

Comment: I didn't expect `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` to make any differences. Unfortunately, I must not have been clear - the Output Window is different from the Package Manager Console. (The similar naming doesn't help.) You can usually access it with `Ctrl+W, O` or use the Quick Launch bar at the top. You'll probably need to change the dropdown... There will be a lot of GET and CACHE lines, with probably one or two errors scattered in.

Comment: There may be an issue specifically with updating Newtonsoft.Json in versions prior to beta-5: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/24

Comment: doesn't look like mvc6 at all. Are you sure you are on mvc 6 ?

Answer (score 2):

This error:
"Severity Code Description Project File Line Error NuGet Package Restore failed for one or more packages. See details in the Output window."

...was resolved for me by ensuring I was running VisualStudio as an Administrator.

Although, the page did not fully render well on the first build.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution that I know of right now is to use `Visual Studio 2013` instead of `2015` to upgrade your packages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem has been resolved. You have to update your NugetPackage Manager:

Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery